# Do I follow the same recommended tire pressure when I change to nitrogen filled tires?

Tags: tires, pressure

I am aware of the recommended tire pressure indicated in the car's user manual and in the driver's door. I've been reading a lot about filling tires with nitrogen and a few of the advantages has caught my interest.

If I do this, do I still follow the same recommended tire pressure indicated for the vehicle?

Comment: FYI - I have been using Nitrogen in my truck tires for over 6 years. I find tire tree wears slower and my tires go 10-20 miles OVER the warranties. I will never use anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to fill using the same tire pressure recommendations. Remember, when you fill your tires with normal air, it is composed of 70% nitrogen in the first place. Pure nitrogen is not going to be that different as to need an adjustment in the pressure.

Comment: Thanks Paulster! Another good answer! Just wanted to ask after watching a video by Fifth Gear on Youtube, saying Nitrogen rises temperature faster. Nitrogen vs Air In Tyres Fifth Gear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmnZ4-EUbIk Thanks!